# What is this Airbus A320 passager seat part?

Tags: airbus-a320, feature-identification, seats

I'm on a Airbus A320 anyone have any idea what the black part on the back of the passager seat is used for?

[image]

Comment: I’m not entirely certain and don’t have time to write a complete answer but I suspect that it may be a card reader for in-flight purchases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s a credit card reader so a passenger can purchase either premium food products or spirits or inflight entertainment items.

Comment: In an A320? Wow. I wouldn't expect such a thing in an aircraft that isn't usually used for long-haul connections. If I didn't know that Ryanair only uses B737's I'd bet this was another "invention" of Mr. O'Leary.

Comment: Yeah, it looks to be a bog standard magstripe reader, no different than the ones that are commonly used for magstripe access cards, library cards, etc on terra firma

Comment: Virgin America used to have [a similar system](https://airlinegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_0312.jpg) (the card reader is harder to see, at the bottom), but Alaska removed it when they bought the airline. Remember that A320 flights can be up to ~7 hours long, so there's demand for entertainment options, though airlines are largely moving to streaming to customer-provided devices now.

Comment: The card reader looks pretty useless if no display is installed.